# psutil can not be found within a flask project

Tags: python, psutil

I have setup a fairly simple flask project. Within this flask project I want to use psutil but its not being found with the import statement.

```
> $ ./satelite.py                                                              
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./satelite.py", line 2, in <module>
    from app import app
  File "/home/neil/monitor/satelite/app/__init__.py", line 4, in     <module>
    from app import views
  File "/home/neil/monitor/satelite/app/views.py", line 6, in <module>
    import psutil
ImportError: No module named psutil
```

However when I use python cli it is.

```
> $ python                                                                     
Python 2.7.6 (default, Mar 22 2014, 22:59:56) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import psutil
>>> print psutil.cpu_percent()
15.3
```

The same can be said for just a straight forward python script being executed separately.

Standard python modules(subprocess, os, etc) are loading fine. I have tried to focus my google-fu on this but I am getting nowhere so would massively appreciate if anyone can point me in the right direction.

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does your first line in satelite.py refers to the same python binary as `which python` in your terminal ?

(This refer to the `#!` line)

Maybe you are using python3 in your satelite.py file.

Comment: That pointed me in the right direction. When flask is setup it copies python libs into flask/bin including easy_install so when I installed psutil it installed it globally but not within the virtualenv.